# SQL Server - Joining two table to fetch data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling to write query to fetch the required information. See below:

Table **Customers**

```
CustId    CustName
1        Andy
2        Rob
3        Craig
4        Rashi
```

Table **Customer Orders**

```
CustId   OrderQuantity
1        3
2        5
3        10
1        2
```

OUTPUT required:

```
CustId    CustName     NumberofOrdersPlaced
1        Andy                  5
2        Rob                   5 
3        Craig                10
4        Rashi                 0
```

If a `Customer` has not placed any order, the `NumberofOrdersPlaced` should set to 0.

I'm struggling with this simple query. Please can someone help.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Does the requirement of each customer being present even if they have no orders suggest a particular type of join to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.custId
   ,c.custName
   ,(select count(1) from CustomerOrders where custId = c.custId) numberoforders
   from Customers c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  c.custid,
  c.custname,
  co.sum(orderquantity) as NumberofOrdersPlaced
from customers c
left join customer_orders co on c.custid = co.custid
group by custid,custname
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a `LEFT JOIN` on the tables.  The `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows in the `customers` table even if there is not a matching row in the `customer_orders` table.

Once you have joined the tables, then you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to replace the `null` value with zero for those customers with no orders:

```
select 
  c.custid,
  c.custname,
  coalesce(sum(co.orderquantity), 0) as NumberofOrdersPlaced
from customers c
left join customer_orders co 
  on c.custid = co.custid
group by c.custid, c.custname
order by c.custid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10bf0/5)